# Which test automation tools that compatible with Docker?

Tags: docker, automation

I am looking for automation testing tools that compatible with Docker Image. Can you guys help me to find it out? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with spotify docker-client: https://github.com/spotify/docker-client

Answer (score 0):

Almost all the testing tool nowadays have support for docker and already they have docker official images. You can try Selenium , Watir, Katalon etc for UI Automation. There are more automation tools for API testing that can be dockerized.

Basically you can dockerize any automation tool as per your need.